# Consider comma separated values in a field as separate values while aggregating in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i want to do aggregation on a field which has values like

doc1_field: "A"
doc2_field: "A, B"
doc3_field: "A, B, C"

What mappings / settings I can use so that when I aggregate on this field I should get results like:

key: A
count: 3

key: "B"
count: 2

key: "C"
count: 3

I have tried adding a comma separated analyzer on the above field but it's not giving me the desired results, I still get results like

key: "A"
count: 1

key: "A, B, C"
count: 1

which is not what I want..

Could you please help in how can I aggregate on this field??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to split the field at ingest time using an ingest pipeline and  a [`split` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/split-processor.html):

Simulating the following ingest pipeline with the same documents you provided would yield this:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "field_name",
          "separator": "\\s*[,;]\\s*"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "field_name": "A"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "field_name": "A, B"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "field_name": "A; B; C"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "doc": {
        "_source": {
          "field_name": [
            "A"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc": {
        "_source": {
          "field_name": [
            "A",
            "B"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc": {
        "_source": {
          "field_name": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This means that instead of indexing `"A, B, C"` you'd index an array containing three separate values: `["A", "B", "C"]` which you can then easily aggregate on and get the results you want.

If you want to go this way, just create the pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/splitter
{
    "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "field_name",
          "separator": "\\s*,\\s*"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

And then index your documents by referencing it:

```
PUT index/_doc/1?pipeline=splitter
{
   "field": "A, B, C"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I was able to separate them at the time of ingestion and it helps a lot.. Just for my understanding could you help me with how can I separate the fields on the basis of more than one separator, i.e. what if some of my fields are also separated by semi-colon, then what can I add in the separator so that it tokenize it irrespective of comma or a semi-colon? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! I've updated my answer with a pattern that takes care of the semicolon also. You can add other separators within the square brackets